# Best way to wait for queue population python multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

It is first time I play with parallel computing seriously.
I am using `multiprocessing` module in python and I am running into this problem:

A queue consumer run in a different process then queue producer, the former should wait the latter to finish its job, before stop iterating over the queue. Sometimes the consumer is faster then producer and the queue stays empty.
If I don't put any condition the program won't stop.

In the sample code I use the wildcard `PRODUCER_IS_OVER` to example what I need.

following code sketch the problem:

```
def save_data(save_que, file_):
    ### Coroutine instantiation
    PRODUCER_IS_OVER = False
    empty = False
    ### Queue consumer
    while not(empty and PRODUCER_IS_OVER):
        try:
            data = save_que.get()
            print("saving data",data)
        except:
            empty = save_que.empty()
            print(empty)
            pass
        #PRODUCER_IS_OVER = get_condition()
    print ("All data saved")
    return

def get_condition():
    ###NameError: global name 'PRODUCER_IS_OVER' is not defined
    if PRODUCER_IS_OVER:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def produce_data(save_que):
    for _ in range(5):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
        data = random.randint(1,10)
        print("sending data", data)
        save_que.put(data)

### Main function here
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Manager, Process
manager = Manager()
save_que = manager.Queue()
file_ = "file"
save_p    = Process(target= save_data, args=(save_que, file_))
save_p.start()
PRODUCER_IS_OVER = False
produce_data(save_que)
PRODUCER_IS_OVER = True
save_p.join()
```

`produce_data` takes variable time and I want the save_p process to start BEFORE populate the queue, in order to consume the queue while is filled.
I think there are workaround to communicate when to stop iteration, but I want to know whether exist a proper way to do it.
I tried both multiprocessing.Pipe and .Lock, but I don't know how implement correctly and efficiently.

SOLVED: is it the best way?

following code implement STOPMESSAGE in the Q, works fine, I can refine it with a class, `QMsg`, in case the language supports only static types.

```
def save_data(save_que, file_):
    # Coroutine instantiation
    PRODUCER_IS_OVER = False
    empty = False
    # Queue consumer
    while not(empty and PRODUCER_IS_OVER):
        data = save_que.get()
        empty = save_que.empty()
        print("saving data", data)
        if data == "STOP":
            PRODUCER_IS_OVER = True
    print("All data saved")
    return


def get_condition():
    # NameError: global name 'PRODUCER_IS_OVER' is not defined
    if PRODUCER_IS_OVER:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def produce_data(save_que):
    for _ in range(5):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        data = random.randint(1, 10)
        print("sending data", data)
        save_que.put(data)
    save_que.put("STOP")


# Main function here
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Manager, Process
manager = Manager()
save_que = manager.Queue()
file_ = "file"
save_p = Process(target=save_data, args=(save_que, file_))
save_p.start()
PRODUCER_IS_OVER = False
produce_data(save_que)
PRODUCER_IS_OVER = True
save_p.join()
```

But this cannot work in case the queue is produced by several separated process: who is going to send the ALT message in that case?

another solution is to store the processes index in a list and execute:

```
def some_alive():
    for p in processes:
        if p.is_alive():
            return True
    return False
```

But `multiprocessing` supports `.is_alive` method only in the parent process, which is limiting in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is the default behavior of `queue.get`. It will wait (block) until an item is available from the queue. Sending a sentinel value is indeed the prefered way to end a child-process.

Your scenario could be simplified to something like that:

```
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process


def save_data(save_que, file_):
    for data in iter(save_que.get, 'STOP'):
        print("saving data", data)
    print("All data saved")
    return


def produce_data(save_que):
    for _ in range(5):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        data = random.randint(1, 10)
        print("sending data", data)
        save_que.put(data)
    save_que.put("STOP")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = Manager()
    save_que = manager.Queue()
    file_ = "file"
    save_p = Process(target=save_data, args=(save_que, file_))
    save_p.start()
    produce_data(save_que)
    save_p.join()
```

---

Edit to answer question in the comment:

> How should I implement the stop message in case the cue is accessed by several different agents and each one has a randomized time for finishing its task?

It's not much different, you have to put as much sentinel values into the queue as much consumers you have.

A utility function which returns a streamlogger to see where the action is:

```
def get_stream_logger(level=logging.DEBUG):
    """Return logger with configured StreamHandler."""
    stream_logger = logging.getLogger('stream_logger')
    stream_logger.handlers = []
    stream_logger.setLevel(level)
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh.setLevel(level)
    fmt = '[%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(processName)s] --- %(message)s'
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)
    sh.setFormatter(formatter)
    stream_logger.addHandler(sh)

    return stream_logger
```

Code with multiple consumers:

```
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
import logging

def save_data(save_que, file_):
    stream_logger = get_stream_logger()
    for data in iter(save_que.get, 'STOP'):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))  # random delay
        stream_logger.debug(f"saving: {data}")  # DEBUG
    stream_logger.debug("all data saved")  # DEBUG
    return


def produce_data(save_que, n_workers):
    stream_logger = get_stream_logger()
    for _ in range(5):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        data = random.randint(1, 10)
        stream_logger.debug(f"producing: {data}")  # DEBUG
        save_que.put(data)

    for _ in range(n_workers):
        save_que.put("STOP")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    file_ = "file"
    n_processes = 2

    manager = Manager()
    save_que = manager.Queue()

    processes = []
    for _ in range(n_processes):
        processes.append(Process(target=save_data, args=(save_que, file_)))

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    produce_data(save_que, n_workers=n_processes)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Example output:

```
[2018-09-02 20:10:35,885 DEBUG    MainProcess] --- producing: 2
[2018-09-02 20:10:38,887 DEBUG    MainProcess] --- producing: 8
[2018-09-02 20:10:38,887 DEBUG    Process-2] --- saving: 2
[2018-09-02 20:10:39,889 DEBUG    MainProcess] --- producing: 8
[2018-09-02 20:10:40,889 DEBUG    Process-3] --- saving: 8
[2018-09-02 20:10:40,890 DEBUG    Process-2] --- saving: 8
[2018-09-02 20:10:42,890 DEBUG    MainProcess] --- producing: 1
[2018-09-02 20:10:43,891 DEBUG    Process-3] --- saving: 1
[2018-09-02 20:10:46,893 DEBUG    MainProcess] --- producing: 5
[2018-09-02 20:10:46,894 DEBUG    Process-3] --- all data saved
[2018-09-02 20:10:50,895 DEBUG    Process-2] --- saving: 5
[2018-09-02 20:10:50,896 DEBUG    Process-2] --- all data saved

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly related, but this solution below allows you to wait until there is something in the queue before acting on it. In my case I have a thread that waits until data is placed on the queue, then spools up a Process

```
from multiprocessing import get_context
import multiprocessing.queues as mpq
import multiprocessing.connection as connection
from threading import Thread

class SpoolingQueue(mpq.Queue):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ctx = get_context()
        super(SpoolingQueue, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs, ctx=ctx)

    def wait(self):
        connection.wait([self._reader])


def task(q:SpoolingQueue):

    while True:
        q.wait()
        print(q.get()) #Do something here knowing that the queue has data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    q=SpoolingQueue()

    canary = Thread(target=task, args=(q,))
    canary.start()

    time.sleep(5)
    q.put('Output')
```